# Horizontally Center Last Odd Item of Gridview Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am using a `Gridview` builder to lazily display my items. My `gridview's` itemcount is 5 and crossAxiscount is 2. Is there a way to horizontally center the 5th item? Thank you for trying to help me.

Here is how my `Gridview` looks like:

```
GridView.builder(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 itemCount: list.length, //the value is 5
 gridDelegate:
  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
     return card(i); //widget that returns a card
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what I should do. Since my `GridView's itemcount` is static and is known which is five, I could simply wrap `card(i)` using the `Wrap` widget and set its `alignment` as well as its `crossAxisAlignment` to center.

Here is how I was able to solve it:

```
Wrap(
 spacing: 8, //vertical spacing
 runSpacing: 8, //horizontal spacing
 alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
   card(0),
   card(1),
   card(2),
   card(3),
   card(4),
  ],
),
```